# Regex in java for the string

Tags: java, regex, split, tokenize

I am very new programmer to Java regular expressions. I do not want to use java split with delimiters and try getting the individual tokens. I don't feel its a neat way. I have the following string

```
"Some String lang:c,cpp,java file:build.java"
```

I want to break up this into three parts

```
1 part containing "Some String" 
2 part containing "c,cpp,java" 
3 String containing "build.java"
```

The `lang:` and `file:` can be placed any where and they are optional.

Comment: Why not `split`? It's certainly not bad.

Comment: Well I feel split makes it more difficult to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The lang: and file: can be placed any where and they are optional.

Try the following expressions to get the language list and the file:

```
String input = "Some String lang:c,cpp,java file:build.java";
String langExpression = "lang:([\\w,]*)";
String fileExpression = "file:([\w\.]*)";

Patter langPattern = Pattern.compile(langExpression);
Matcher langMatcher = langPattern.matcher(input);
if (langMatcher.matches()) {
  String languageList = langMatcher.group(1);
}

Patter filePattern = Pattern.compile(fileExpression );
Matcher fileMatcher = filePattern.matcher(input);
if (fileMatcher .matches()) { 
  String filename= fileMatcher.group(1);
}
```

This should work with `lang:xxx file:xxx` as well as `file:xxx lang:xxx` as long as the language list or the filename don't contain whitespaces. This would also work if lang: and/or file: was missing.

Would you also expect a string like this: `file:build.java Some String lang:c,cpp,java`?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will try this . This will be a very good head start to get regex working for me.

Comment: @Nandish You could also have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info which IMHO is a very good reference.

Answer (score 1):

What is so "unmaintainable" about using `split`?

```
        String str = "Some String lang:c,cpp,java file:build.java";
        String[] s  = str.split("(lang|file):");
```

Answer (score 0):

While `split` can do what you want to achieve, you can write your own code using `substring` and `indexOf` methods. This will be far faster than using `split` in terms of performance.

Comment: If the OP is concerned about maintainability, I guarantee that rolling your own variant of split using substring and indexOf is not going to help in that regard.  Furthermore, this smells of premature optimization to me.